# I can't install one of the gems in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I'm trying to get my git repository work, but i can't. In my command line i'm at the reprository's directory. I gave the "bundle install" command to get all the gems i need to work, but i can't finish it. It keeps telling me this error:

```
Using bcrypt 3.1.10
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150726-3952-czpz5l.rb extcon
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating debug_inspector-i386-mingw32.def
make: *** No rule to make target `/C/Ruby22/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h'
y `debug_inspector.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/
ector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32
ug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundle
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds befor
bundling.
```

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/24666830/1197775

Comment: Like juanpastas said, this kind of thing is usually a compatibility problem. What version of ruby and rails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have Windows machine.  Make sure you installed right version of [Ruby Devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/)  so that native extensions can be built.